# Integration JqZoom and Jquery Ad Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm doing so far work's well in Firefox, and webkit browers (safari, and chrome, not tested in maxthone) And actually it's pretty simple I'm just adding an event hover changing the width and height in the gallery to gain space and let the image with the zoom of the Jqzoom appears.

And this all the javascript code needed for that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
    callbacks:
        {
            afterImageVisible: function () {
                $('div.ad-image a').jqzoom({
                    zoomType: 'reverse',
                    preloadText: locale.gallery.preloadText,
                    title: false,
                    zoomWidth: 500,
                    zoomHeight: 300,
                    preloadImages: true
                });

                $("div.zoomPad img").hover(function () {
                    var $container = $("div.ad-image");
                    $container.css('width', '850px').css('height', '302px');
                    $container.parent().css('width', '850px').css('height', '302px');
                    $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
                }, function () {
                    var $container = $("div.ad-image");
                    $container.css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
                    $container.parent().css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
                    $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
                });
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Now my question it's Why this doesn't work in IE? I started to debug, but I don't see any errors, and it's drive me crazy, because the hover event it's fired

[Here's my live example](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/KU6NU/3/)

**UPDATE**

Testing I'm realize that the event that it's bring me troubles it's the mouse out so I change A little be the code to work at least the `mouseover` or `mouseenter` I tried with `mouseleave` and `mouseout` event. and still without good results

```
    $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
        callbacks:
            {
                afterImageVisible: function () {
                    $('div.ad-image a').jqzoom({
                        zoomType: 'reverse',
                        preloadText: locale.gallery.preloadText,
                        title: false,
                        zoomWidth: 500,
                        zoomHeight: 300,
                        preloadImages: true
                    });

                    if (!$.browser.msie) {
                        $("div.zoomPad img").hover(function () {
                            var $container = $("div.ad-image");
                            $container.css('width', '850px').css('height', '302px');
                            $container.parent().css('width', '850px').css('height', '302px');
                            $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
                        }, function () {
                            var $container = $("div.ad-image");
                            $container.css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
                            $container.parent().css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
                            $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $("div.zoomPad img").on({
                            mouseenter: function () {
                                var $container = $("div.ad-image");
                                $container.css('width', '850px').css('height', '302px');
                                $container.parent().css('width', '850px').css('height', '302px');
                                $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
                            }
//                            ,mouseleave: function () {
//                                var $container = $("div.ad-image");
//                                $container.css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
//                                $container.parent().css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
//                                $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
//                            }
                        });
```

my last version [of live exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/KU6NU/18/)

Comment: read this link might help you - [http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved my problem by change the selector and how i attach the listener

```
$('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
animate_first_image: true,
callbacks: {
    afterImageVisible: function() {
        $('div.ad-image a').jqzoom({
            zoomType: 'standar',
            preloadText: locale.gallery.preloadText,
            title: false,
            zoomWidth: 500,
            zoomHeight: 300,
            preloadImages: true
        });

        $("div.zoomPad").mouseenter(function() {
            var $container = $("div.ad-image");
            $container.css('width', '850px').css('height', '350px');
            $container.parent().css('width', '850px').css('height', '350px');
            $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            var $container = $("div.ad-image");
            $container.css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
            $container.parent().css('width', '300px').css('height', '300px');
            $('div.ad-prev').css('width', '25px');
        });
    }
}

});​
```

Here's my live example

http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/KU6NU/20/

Answer (score 0):

i haven't taken much look at your fiddle example, but as i understand IE upto ver6 does not support hover except for `anchor <a>` tag. Also later versions have reported bugs.

check this for more detail http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover